# Adding an add-in command to the Add context menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sdk, add-in

I'm trying to add a command to the `Add` context menu in Visual Studio 2012 (When you right click on the Controllers folder in an MVC project and navigate to Add)

I tried the divide and concur approach and added the command to all the command bars by doing

```
var cmdBars = (CommandBars)(_applicationObject.CommandBars);

foreach (CommandBar cc in cmdBars)
{
    if (cc.Index >= 1 && cc.Index <= 456)
    {
        command.AddControl(cmdBars[cc.NameLocal]);
    }
}
```

This is adding the command to the parent menu as illustrated by the image below, but not to the `Add` menu. How can I add my command to this menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a MSDN article that pointed me into the right direction,[Working with Command Bar Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141695(v=office.10).aspx)

In short, each command bar may contain a set of controls. The sub menus will be contained within this set of controls and you can access these sub menus the exact same way the original set of command bars was accessed.

So I did the following

```
// Get menu when right clicking the Controllers folder in a MVC project.
var folderCommandBar = (CommandBars)(_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Folder"];

// Get the Add sub menu.
var addCommandBarControl = folderCommandBar .Controls["Add"];

// Cast the control to a command bar popup.
var addCommandBarPopup  = (CommandBarPopup)addCommandBarControl;

// Now add the command.
command.AddControl(addCommandBarPopup, 1);
```

I now successfully added the command to the Add sub menu as illustrated by the image below
[image]